# Identifying word documents opened by Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium

In my Selenium project word document is being opened as a report.
How can I identify whether the document is opened or not using Selenium webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

In short, unless the document opens utilizing the browser, then you can't with Selenium WebDriver.  Selenium only has access to what the browser itself has access to.  If the browser is handing this off to the OS or MS Office to handle the specifics then you lose access to it.

You could try to intercept the communication and determine when the code to call the word document to open is executed, but that would be custom code and depend on the application itself.

Personally I think the best way would be to instantiate an `OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions` class instance and then specify the specific keystrokes to capture the screen and save it.  Then switch back to the browser window `driver.switchto().window()` and continue.  Then you can verify manually that the screen capture has the word document in it after the test is completed.

Comment: Thanks for your comments,but my requirement is to check whether word document is opened in the node or not and also I need to close that document in the node.

Comment: There are some other possibilities then although not "Selenium", but can be tied into the test.
Is this always a windows OS?  What language is your test in?